# Suggested method to handle large dataset for SSRS and Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a situation where I have been asked to create some reports on a large dataset - around 350million records in SQL server 2012.  The idea is that I create a report using different reporting tools to show the relative pros and cons of each.  We have the options of using Qliksense, SSRS and Excel (I know this is not a reporting tool).

I've created a Qliksense model which handles the data volume reasonably well.  The data takes a few seconds to process when we change dimensions or measures but it's manageable.  However, I am unsure about how to handle this with SSRS and especially Excel.  Clearly we need to summarise the data. This is fine as we always intended to show data summarised/aggregated by some dimension.

What I could do is create a summarised data set but the issue is that we ideally want to be able to see this data by different dimensions.  Short of creating a table for STATE and another for PRODUCT and another for SALESMAN etc, the only other way I can think of is to build some kind of cube.  Or perhaps one of the clever folk frequenting this site can suggest a better way? If the solution could handle some way to drill down, all the better.

I'd appreciate advice on how best to manage this large volume of data in such a way that I am able to report on it.

Comment: Is SSAS in the picture at all? (Isn't specifically mentioned above so want to make sure)

Comment: PowerBI could do this for you if you want to use Excel https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/?

Comment: We do have the option of SSAS.  Not clear on how this might help but perhaps you can give me some ideas?  PowerBI is not (currently) an option due to compliance requirements.  We cannot store data on the cloud.

Comment: PowerBI does not have to be on the cloud. You can use the free desktop version and just store the data in a local PBIX file just as you would with Excel and an XLSX file.